# Парсинг содержимого файла

Tags: c

Есть файл с таким содержанием:
строка,строка,строка,...,

Записываю в него так:

```
char bufffer[] = read();
fprintf(fileDescriptor, "%s,", buffer);
```

как можно прочитать каждое значение строк, разделенных ",", через цикл?

Comment: Ответ на enSO: [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528)

Comment: `man strsep` поможет. А вообще есть готовые парсеры CSV.

Comment: Может ли строка быть пустой?